# Is there any software that can allow me to prettily make my (java) code a pdf, with std inputs and outputs?

Tags: pdf, code-beautification

I'm a high school student, and for my course I need to submit my code, its input and outputs as a pdf. We did this through JDoodle. However JDoodle simply wasn't that good with large files, say 100 lines. Is there any software or website that can do the same job, but with larger files.